# Error "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, 'Unknown error 1048')"

Tags: python, django-models

When typing the code, `python manage.py shell--->aa.save()`, this error appears:

> `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, 'Unknown error 1048')`

How can I solve it?

Following is my code,

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    content=models.TextField()
    is_show=models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        db_table="article"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


>>> from guestbook.models import Article
>>> Article.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> aa = Article()
>>> aa
<Article: >
>>> aa.title
''
>>> aa.title = "hello"

>>> aa.title
'hello'
>>> aa.save()
```

**Error**

> File "C:\path\to\directory\containing\other\environments\site\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet packet.check_error() 
>   File "C:\path\to\directory\containing\other\environments\site\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data) 
>   File "C:\path\to\directory\containing\other\environments\site\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception raise errorclass(errno, errval) django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, 'Unknown error 1048')

Comment: Did you migrate your model?

Comment: I did ,is it the MySQL privilege problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because you're trying to save a model instance with required fields missing. You can add `null=True` or a default values in your model attributes. For example:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    created_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    content=models.TextField(null=True)
    is_show=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```